# reducing memory usage

Tags: c++

i am developing a project in which i have used many classes.
for creating classes i have used the new operator...example, in banana class i have an instance variable of class apples......

**THIS IS A SCALED DOWN REPRESENTATION OF WHAT I WANT TO SAY & DOES NOT REPRESENT THE CODE WORD-TO-WORD...SO PLEASE DO NOT POINT AT SYNTAX ERRORS...BUT TRY TO UNDERSTAND THE METHODOLOGY**

in header file (banana.h):

```
static int counter = 0;
class banana
{
  public:
  apples *ap_obj;//(apple is a class defined another file apples.cpp)
  int *index;
}
```

in banana.cpp :

```
class banana
{
  banana::banana(void)
  {
    ap_obj = new apples;
    index = new int;
    *index = ++counter;
  }
};
```

my first question is that, is my method correct in terms of memory efficiency?
( i know that i dont have any run time error for sure)

my second question is that, i want to access a banana object in 1 of my methods of any class by using the index (plz note that every banana object has a unique index) variable.
for this i am thinking of using another class registry(because i want to store indexes of many classes's objects).
i am thinking of storing the pointer of 1st object of any class in my registry class.
& for accessing the pointer of any nth object of a class, i plan to use pointer arithmatics on the 1st object using the index variable...example

```
class registry
{
  banana *base_obj;//this value will be initialised when i create the 1st object of banana class
  banana *registry::get_nth_object(int shift);
  {
    return *(base_obj + shift);//shift is the index variable of banana class
  }
};
```

in any other class i can just call **get_nth_object** & pass the index no of the object whose pointer i want & i will get that point.

is there anything wrong in my code?
or if anything can be improved please help me.

for refernce i use http://www.cplusplus.com.
i am a mech engg student so please pardon me if i have made any stupid mistake

Comment: You can improve it by using vectors instead of array/pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should find out what kind of relatioship your banana->apple relation is. If it is a composition (A banana is composed of its apple and...) the simplest think is to store an apple instance in a banana.

```
class banana
{
  apple apple_;  // a banana HAS A apple
};
```

If this is true, but you have myriads of bananas and there are a number of apples that a equal you could implement the [Flyweight Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern) to safe memory usage. But you shouldn't do this because you THINK you have a memory problem, but because you MEASURED that you have a memory problem due to apples.

If your relationship is more a shared ownership, you should store a pointer to the apple instance in banana and think about where to store the apple objects. The easiest way would be to store `std::shared_ptr<apple>` and let the reference counter control the apple lifetime.

You're second question was how to store and access banana Objects. I would introduce a `BananaRepository` which is responsible for storing and retrieving bananas.

```
class BananaRepository
{
  typedef XYZType BananaID;
  Banana& GetByID(BananaID  id);
  BananaID Add(Banana& b);
};
```

You should abstract the kind of used ID and the storage, so client code does not depend on that details. Each banana has a ID and i can get a banana from the repository using this id. The easiest implementation would be with banana::ID = vector::size_type and a vector in BananaRepository.

```
class BananaRepository
{
public:
  typedef std::vector<Banana>::size_type BananaID;

  Banana& GetByID(BananaID  id)
  {
    return bananas_.at(id);
  }

  BananaID Add(Banana& b)
  {
     bananas_.push_back(b);
     return bananas_.size() - 1;
  }

private:
  std::vector<Banana> bananas_;
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Directly embedding is more memory-efficient (it saves you both the overhead of a pointer and that of a heap allocation, and improves locality of reference):

```
class banana
{
  private:
  apples ap_obj;
  int index;
}
```

Note that you forgot to `new` index in your original code. I'm not even sure if I understand the need for it. Is *only* used to find a particular `banana`? If so, it shouldn't be a member of `banana` at all. And why store an index anyway? The usual way to refer to a particular instance is with a `banana*`.

Comment: +1 but you should explain him why :-) It shouldn't be an "ipse dixit" :-) :-) (and probably you should tell him that there are differences with default copy constructors, and the need of deleting if he uses a pointer... and probably many other things)

Comment: this was a scaled down example...there are currently 5 classes & each class has about 10 methods each.
i want to access ap_obj any banana object in any method of any class without going out of scope..so the use of new operator.

Answer (score 1):

first of all, the syntax for banana constructor itself is incorrect. It should NOT be surrounded by  text class banana {};

Second, allocating memory on the heap using new will be fast enough for what you need to do. You shouldn't do it any other way (i.e. don't use malloc). So you are fine in that point.

As for your registry example, get_nth_object will only work if ALL of your banana instances were allocated in contiguous areas of memory.... something you do not have control of when you allocate memory using new. If you allocated memory for your banana pointers using new bananas[size] that would be better, and the memory would be contiguous.

Even if you did get them all spaced regularly in memory, what if you need to delete a banana? Or two or three? Or half a dozen? Pretty soon you will have do some real intense record keeping to keep things working.

I myself would prefer to assign a unique ID to each banana in it's constructor when it's created, and in banana's constructor insert itself into an associative container like a map (i.e. std::map)(use #include  in your code). I would use the unique ID as the key, and then you could use the pointer to the banana as the value. In the destructor for banana I would then have the banana remove itself from the registry.

Your registry would be responsible for owning the associative container (i.e. the map).

Answer (score 0):

> i know that i dont have any run time error for sure

Well, it seems you *have* a runtime error (or more). Declaring

```
 int *index;
```

leaves `index`as an uninitialized pointer, and

```
 *index = ++counter;
```

puts the contents of `counter` to the place where `index` points to (which is totally undefined where this might be). Surely this will be a cause of strange errors.

Perhaps you wanted to declare

```
  int index;
```

and

```
 index = ++counter;
```

I assume?

Answer (score 0):

1. For storing scalar data, you don't need to use pointers. That's why `int index`. Assign some "impossible" value to know that the index is illegal.
2. Your method `get_nth_object` is wrong. You can't be sure that all `banana's` are allocated in consistent memory block. Thus, you can't use such linear address arithmetic to get objects. Find information about using dynamic arrays or lists. In case of arrays, you might want to check info about overloading subscription operator